# Charge conjugation of symplectic Majorana spinors in 4+1 dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spinors, majorana-fermions, supergravity, clifford-algebra

In the book "Supergravity" written by Freedman & van Proeyen, a symplectic Majorana spinor is defined in eq. (3.86)

$$ \chi^i = \varepsilon^{ij} (\chi^j)^C, \tag{3.86}$$

where the upper index $C$ denotes charge conjugation and $\varepsilon^{ij} \varepsilon_{kj} = \delta^i_k$.

Below the above equation in the book, there is an exercise asking one to show that, in 4+1 dimensions, given the symplectic Majorana spinors $\psi^i$ and $\chi^i$, the quantity $\overline{\psi}^i \chi^j \varepsilon_{ji}$ is purely imaginary ($\overline{\psi}^i= (\psi^i)^T C$, with $C$ the charge conjugation matrix). I tried to show this last statement by doing the following computation

\begin{align}
(\overline{\psi}^i \chi^j \varepsilon_{ji})^C &=  (\overline{\psi}^i)^C (\chi^j)^C \varepsilon_{ji} \\
&=\varepsilon_{ki} \varepsilon_{lj} \overline{\psi}^k \chi^l \varepsilon_{ji} \\
& = \varepsilon_{lk}\overline{\psi}^k \chi^l \\
& = \overline{\psi}^i \chi^j \varepsilon_{ji}\,.
\end{align}

Consequently, I get that $\overline{\psi}^i \chi^j \varepsilon_{ji}$ is real and not imaginary as the exercise states.

Is there a mistake in my computation? Or is the book statement that $\overline{\psi}^i \chi^j \varepsilon_{ji}$ should be imaginary wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your first line, you divide the C operation, but you should take into account (3.79). In 5D (-t_0 t_1)=-1.